# Dealing with shared registry values

Tags: wix

I'm working on an installer that's creating registry values and deleting them on uninstall.  However some of the registry values I'm working with could be shared with other companion applications.  I only want it to remove the registry values if it's the only component using those registries.  If other apps that use those registry values are installed, my uninstall should not remove them.  How would I go about creating this conditional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is achieved by using basic MSI component rules:

- All MSIs that set this shared registry value need to have the value set as the KeyPath for the component.
- The components need to have the same component-guid.

If these are common across all MSIs, then the registry value should only have its refcount decremented instead of the entire value removed when one product is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Building on jbudrea's answer, for me this is a scenario where a merge module is helpful.  You can have 10 components in 10 installers and hope you kept the GUIDs in sync or you can do it once in a merge module and reference it 10 times.  Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY).   This is mainly for registry data such as COM registration or file extension handlers.

For some data, such as configuration data, permanent components  might make sense.  The footprint is small and it's nice to have the data still there after you uninstall everything and then reinstall one of the products.  This also assumes you are doing some property persistence pattern.

One final thought for configuration data would be to not do it in the install at all.   Instead have the setting saved at first run of the application and now the install won't manage it and will leave it behind on uninstall like above.  (I like to think of configuration data as user data typically which MSI says to leave behind.)